# What happened to certain enemies at the end of Series 02, Episode 13, "Doomsday"?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of Series 02, Episode 13, "Doomsday", the Doctor

> opens the breach between the two Earths, then reverses it, which has the effect of pulling everything which has crossed the Void (as doing so saturates the object in Void material) back into the Void.

What happened to

> the Cybermen created after the invasion, on Earth, which never crossed the Void? Presumably they were not saturated in the Void material, so they would still remain?

Comment: @amflare She means the humans on Earth that were converted, not any that crossed.  At least one is addressed in a [Torchwood episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberwoman), but I don't think anything else is done about any others.

Comment: They were swallowed by the Plot Hole.

Comment: Oh, right, duh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Torchwood episode [Cyberwoman](http://www.chakoteya.net/Torchwood/104.htm):

> OWEN: These things brought down Torchwood One. **But they were all destroyed.** Why is there one in our bloody basement!
>
> GWEN: Just tell me what it does.
>
> OWEN: It's the remnants of a conversion unit. This machinery turns humans into Cybermen.

One may assume that those who didn't cross The Void, who weren't converted with significant use of parts taken across The Void, and who survived the initial Battle at Canary Wharf, were destroyed by local forces. The remnants of Torchwood and U.N.I.T. seem like logical candidates.

Comment: And, presumably, the Daleks took out quite a few.

Comment: Indeed, but with the Daleks also being sucked into the void, they would have been unavailable to address the converted Cybermen who are the crux of the question.

Comment: I assume they could have killed several before the void was opened.

Comment: Answer clarified, thanks.

Comment: Grateful for the "[Cybermen] parts taken across the Void" bit--that seems reasonable, to me.